# Что такое йотовый суффикс? или «йотовый» суффикс принадлежности?

Tags: ономастика, антропонимика, йотовый-суффикс, мёртвые-аффиксы

> ...Данное название справедливо связывают со святилищем Велеса, которое
>   естественно ожидать в ближайшей округе средневековой Ладоги - древней
>   столицы Северной Руси. Лингвистически форма Велеша - это
>   прилагательное, закономерно образованное с помощью «йотового» суффикса
>   принадлежности от основы Белее- (Велес-j- > Велеш-, буквально
>   «Велесово (место)»).
>
> «Йотовый» суффикс принадлежности, потерявший употребительность после
>   XII века, являлся весьма характерным для названий, производных от имен
>   людей. В «йотовой» деривации применительно к теониму читаются не
>   только глубокая архаичность рассматриваемых топонимов, но и древний
>   анимизм (индивидуальная принадлежность живому божеству)...

Мне о нём рассказывают, можно сказать, в картинках, а я не вижу в упор, где и как работает йот.

> Среди выявленных фамилий основную часть представляют патронимы.
>   «Первоначальные  п а т р о н и м ы  (особый тип именования по отцу) не
>   вполне соответствовали нашему отчеству или фамилии в современном
>   юридическом понимании, а были своеобразной категорией, совмещавшей то
>   и другое. Русские патронимы отвечали на вопрос “чей?” и образовывались
>   с суффиксом -ов (-ев) от основ, оканчивающихся на согласные:
>   Иван-Иванов, Чулок-Чулков, Андрей-Андреев, Яков-Яковлев (после губного
>   добавлялся согласный л), с суффиксом -ин, если основа оканчивалась на
>   -а (-я): Фома-Фомин, Илья-Ильин, Квашня-Квашнин, а также с особым очень древним “йотовым” суффиксом: Ярославль, Рослиславль,
>   Всеволожь... Патронимы — это очень древние слова. Они встречаются даже
>   в списке русских послов 945 года, включенном в Лаврентьевскую
>   летопись».

Ещё пример употребления:

> В названии порога Ладоли с некоторой натяжкой можно усмотреть
>   притяжательную форму с йотовым суффиксом от Ладул или Ладол -
>   уменьшительного варианта имени Ладомир, и, значит, поблизости от
>   порога могла некогда находится деревня Ладоли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Йотация - это изменение согласных в сочетании с j, ведущее к смягчению в результате воздействия звука [j]. Похоже, цитируемые труды называют йотовым суффиксом суффикс образованный в словах, полученных добавлением суффикса к слову с йотацией на конце.